# how to change the datatype for a column in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I want to change the datatype of a column from bigint to double in spark for a delta table.

AnalysisException: Cannot update spark_catalog.default.tablename field column_name: bigint cannot be cast to decimal(10,2); line 1 pos 0;
AlterColumn resolvedfieldname(StructField(column_name,LongType,true)), DecimalType(10,2)

ALTER TABLE tablename
ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE decimal(10, 2)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same in my environment. I got this output:

Following the below approach it will change the datatype for a column in spark sql.

> **Approach 1**

**Pyspark**

First directly read the Delta table as a data frame and use the **cast function** to change data types. **Note** : **my_table1** it is my delta table

```
%python

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df= spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table1")
df1 = df.withColumn("age", col("age").cast("double"))
```

[image]

> **Approach 2:**

**Spark SQL:**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table1
SELECT id, name, CAST(age AS DOUBLE) AS age FROM my_table1;
```

[image]